# Form Submit Error - Angular 2 Javascript

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

[image]

Can anyone check this image link and explain me why this error is coming after form submit. I have submitted form using `(submit)` and navigated to next page by using `this.router.navigate(['/Todos']);`. Here is my code,

**login.html**

```
<form #simpleForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(simpleForm, user)" novalidate>

    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" [(ngModel)]="user.name" ngControl="name" #name="ngForm" required />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>

</form>
```

**login.js**

```
(function (app) {

    app.LoginComponent = ng.core
            .Component({
                selector: 'login',
                templateUrl: 'login.html',
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: [ng.router.Router, function (router) {
                    this.router = router;
                    this.user = {};
                }],
                onSubmit: function (form, user) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/Todos']);
                },
            });

    ng.router.CanActivate(function (next, prev) {
        return true; //return false to cancel navigation
    })(app.LoginComponent);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: There is a toolbar button in the editor to add images, why adding a link? The link will break eventually and make the question useless for future visitiors. The error should be added as text directly to the question anyway to make it searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786

Use `setTimeout()` to work around

```
onSubmit: function (form, user) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.router.navigate(['/Todos']);
  }, 10);
},
```

Comment: Great. It is working. Thanks. And I have removed the image link and added image in my question.